# Prove that for every $x$ in the area of $0$ exists: $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I need to prove 2 things:

Prove that for every $x$ in a neighbourhood of $0$ exists: $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}.$

What I did is that I calculated the derivatives of $\ln(1+x)$ and constructed an equation which I can build a sequence from:

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$

$f''(x) = -\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

And so on.. but I don't know if this is enough to prove because I didn't show that the remainder approaches $0$.. so I think I got this the wrong way.

Can someone please show me how to prove this?

Thanks

Comment: You would like then to show that the series converges to the $\log(1+x)$, right? or you have the sum, and want to show that it equals $\log(1+x)$?

Answer (score 1):

You should already know that for any $|y|<1$ we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n y^n = \frac{1}{1+y},$$
so what happens by integrating both sides over $[0,x]$? It happens that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{n}=\log(1+x).$$

Comment: Hi, this looks like the right way to go. But as far as I know I need to prove that the remainder of the series approaches to zero and then the series is equal to the function. Now you showed that the series is equal to the function, can I conclude that because of this the limit of $R_n = 0$? (Because it's an if and only if statement) Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @FigureItOut: we have to provide a bound for the tails of the series. For instance: $$\left|\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|\leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n\geq N}|x|^n = \frac{|x|^N}{N(1-|x|)}.$$